# Python Error - TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported

Tags: python, tkinter, anaconda, typeerror, pyglet

I think this is a not a programming specific bug, but is caused by some libraries.

I am transferring my project to a new PC, which I have freshly setup with anaconda etc. using python 3.7.6. Executing the task on the old machine works fine, here I have also used anaconda with python 3.7 (not sure if it was 3.7.6 but I could check this, i just used while creating the environment python=3.7).

When I now try to run my program, I receive:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
...    
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

The error is quite long, but it is caused by the following libraries:
calling gym.envs which then calls some pyglet.libs

The last line in the error is

```
...from pyglet.libs.x11 import xlib
  File "...7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/libs/x11/xlib.py", line 2928, in <module>
    XEHeadOfExtensionList.argtypes = [XEDataObject]
```

Thank you for your help! I do not know how to solve this or even start solving it.

Comment: Seems to be a problem python 3.7.6+ version. Found [this thread](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues/112) about the problem. Could you double-check what version of pyglet you're running? Version `1.4.9` should resolve the problem according to the above thread.

Comment: If I want to update pyglet I reveice

ERROR: gym 0.15.4 has requirement pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0, but you'll have pyglet 1.4.10 which is incompatible.

Gym is not compatible with this new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there is simply no support currently for using gym+pyglet in python version 3.7.6+.

The pyglet error is fixed in 1.4.9+ but gym is currently not compatible with those versions.

Still it is possible to simply downgrade python to 3.7.4 and everything works fine as it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade your pyttsx3 version:

```
pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```